# Excel VBA If Then Function conditional on cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I want to calculate a price based on a proposed discount % or calculate a discount based on a proposed price.

I need users to be able to use either parameter and adjust back and forth to determine their ideal price.

I have coded the formulas so that nothing is overwritten by the user but have a problem as the 'value if false' element of the "IF" formula is dependent on a zero value in one column and so resets if the user doesn't manually adjust this before inputting a figure into another.  This results in the new figure being reset.

Ideally I would like the sheet to reset the value in column "Proposed Promo POR%" to zero if a value is input in "Promo Price per Unit".  Is this possible?

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("b21:b26")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$i21:$i26").Formula ="=IF(Proposal!$b21>Formulae!$a$5,Proposal!$g21-(Proposal!$g21*Proposal!$b21),  (Proposal!$g21-Proposal!$i21)/Proposal!$g21)"
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

For clarity Formulae!$a$5 is zero and it is column $i21:$i26 that the user will enter a price in if they want to.  If they do enter something here then column b should reset to zero.

This is a screenshot of the columns and headers in my sheet

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `Worksheet_Change` event will help you. `Worksheet_SelectionChange` fires each time a user *changes the active cell*, whereas `Worksheet_Change` fires anytime a user *makes an edit to any cell(s)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$i21:$i26"")) Is Nothing _ 
    And Target.Rows.Count = 1 and Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
    'assumes event will fire only on changing one cell at a time

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0,-7).Value = 0
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: *(+1) from my side.* Still, I am not sure if you might want to add the condition `IF` something has been actually entered. Maybe something like `If Trim(Target.Value2) <> vbNullString And Isnumeric(Target.Value2) Then`... just a thought.

Comment: Good thought @Ralph. Will leave for OP to add at his discretion.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I think I know what you're getting at but I'm quite new to VBA so would appreciate a bit more guidance as to how I actually construct the code with my specific conditional calculations included.

Comment: @LBow509 - *I would like the sheet to reset the value in column "Proposed Promo POR%" to zero if a value is input in "Promo Price per Unit".* - This is what I have done in code in this answer.

Comment: Also, you can use R1C1 notation for the formula. It will be a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this I really appreciate it.  Unfortunately though the code you've provided isn't working for me - I'm getting a compile error message.   In a nutshell I want the sheet to perform the following steps:

Comment: 1: If a value is entered in col b then formula based on this value. 2: If a manual value is entered in col I then reset col b to 0 and formula based on new value. I was close with my original code in that I could do either calculation but the new value in I was always being overridden by the value in col B. Sorry if I’m not being clear but I really appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: I am unclear on the formula. If value is entered in column B, you want to the formula in column I to be as stated in original question. However, this formula refers to column I in it, so that is not possible, as you want to a formula to refer to itself. If I misunderstanding, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks @Scott.  So to clarify I want the following to happen.    1) If % in Column B is greater than zero calculation in Column I is 'Col G-(Col G*Col B).   2) If a value manually entered in Column I, reset Column B to zero and run, in Column H, calculation (Col G - Col I)/Col G.    I want users to be able to adjust either column B or Column I alternately to try and determine final price without overwriting formulas needed to make the calculations work in the columns detailed above or the rest of the sheet.  I hope that clarifies and thank you again for your help!